# API for getting xml from .ppt

Tags: xml, powerpoint

I already tried opening the .ppt file -> Save As -> PowerPoint XML Presentation, but the xml I get is strange, unclean :(
Is there some API I can use to get xml from power point file?
The OS is Windows 7. The .ppt file is Office 2007.

Comment: You might have better luck if you provide a few minimal details.  Version of PowerPoint, platform (Mac/Windows), what programming tools you're working with.  And you might want to describe what you mean by "strange, unclean".  Could it simply mean "not like other XML I've seen"?  ;-)

Comment: I'm working in C#, but I don't have to make the conversion via code. I'm trying to convert the .ppt file via some kind of program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PPT 2007 files are zip files with a different extension; they contain mostly xml files that describe the contents of the presentation.  There are freely available libraries that allow you to work with the contents of ZIP files (INFOZIP for one).

XML is something like a database file in the sense that an XML file can contain pretty much any data the author wants it to, expressed in any way that makes sense, so long as it adheres to a few basic standards.

Considering the potential complexity of a PPT presentation, it shouldn't be any surprise to see complex XML representing it.  MS has quite a lot of documentation on their Office XML formats.  You might want to start here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358825